# Different output when using Get-SPSite vs Get-SPWebApplication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Trying to get a grasp on how the sharepoint object properties correlate to the sharepoint commands. I have 3 scripts that I am testing and 2 output the same display despite using Get-SPSite or Get-SPWebApplication:

**#1**

```
$siteurl = Get-SPSite "http://sharepoint/" -Limit All

# Get Site Collection
$webapp = $siteurl.WebApplication

foreach($site in $webapp.Sites) {
    Write-Host $site

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
        Write-Host `t$web
    }

}
```

Outputs the same results as

**#2**

```
$webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint/"

foreach($site in $webapp.Sites) {
    Write-Host $site

    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
        Write-Host `t$web
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/appcatalog
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/devtest
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/publishing
...
```

So now if I run the following script, I seem to get more sites:

**#3**

```
# Get all Webapplictons
$SPWebApps = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint/"

# Get all sites
$SPSites = $SPWebApp | Get-SPsite -Limit all

foreach($SPSite in $SPSites) {
    # Get all websites
    Write-Host $SPSite
}
```

**Results**

```
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:1234
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/appcatalog
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/devtest
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint/sites/publishing
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:27741
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:27741/personal/...
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:27741/personal/...
SPSite Url=http://sharepoint:27741/personal/...
```

What am I missing? How can I correlate the properties such as `.Sites`,`.AllWebs` to their objects such as `Get-SPSite` and `Get-SPWebApplication`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error in your code. Run the below code( from method #3) it will return the same output

```
# Get all Webapplictons
$SPWebApps = Get-SPWebApplication "http://sharepoint/"

# Get all sites
$SPSites = $SPWebApps | Get-SPsite -Limit all

foreach($SPSite in $SPSites) {
    # Get all websites
    Write-Host $SPSite
}
```

Basically on the this line `$SPSites = $SPWebApp | Get-SPsite -Limit all` You miss the leading s in front of the $spwebapp**S**...this command get all the sites in the farm( sharepoint & sharepoint:27741). while your other two method return the sites collection from a specific web app which is `http://sharepoint/`